# Determining continuity in topological spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Fix a point $b \in \mathbb{R}.$ The topology $\tau_{b}$ is generated by all intervals of the form $(x,\infty),$ where $x$ is less than $b$ as well as all intervals of the form $(−\infty,y),$ where $y$ is bigger than $b.$ In other words, the topology $\tau_{b}$ has subbasis given by

$$ S = \{ (-\infty, y) \}_{y \in \mathbb R \,\,\text{&} \,\,y > b }\,\, \cup \{ (x, \infty) \}_{x \in \mathbb R \,\,\text{&} \,\,x < b }.$$

Consider two different topologies $\tau_{0}$ and $\tau_{1}$ when $b = 0$ and $b = 1$ respectively. Let $(X = \mathbb R, \tau_X = \tau_{0})$ and $(Y = \mathbb R, \tau_Y = \tau_{1})$ be topological spaces.

a) I want to determine if  $p,q,r : X \to Y $ are continuous or not where

i) $p(x) = x$

ii) $ q(x) = x^2 + 1 $

iii) $r(x) = \text{cos}(x).$

b) More generally, suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with respect to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ in both the domain and codomain. I want to find general conditions for when such a function will be continuous when domain is endowed with $\tau_0$ and codomain is endowed with $\tau_1.$

$\mathbf{My \,\, attempt}:$

a) I'm appealing to the following theorem: Let $(X , \tau_X)$ and $(Y, \tau_Y)$ be topological spaces, and suppose $B$ is a basis for $\tau_Y.$ Then a function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous iff for every $V \in \mathcal{B},$ we have $f^{-1}(V) \in \tau_X.$

A basis for $\tau_1$ is $ \mathcal{B} =\{ (x, y) \}_{x,y \in \mathbb R \,\,\text{&} \,\,x < 1 < y } .$

i) No. Choose $V = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}) \in \mathcal{B}.$ Then $f^{-1}(V) = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}) \notin \tau_{0}$ because it doesn't contain $0.$

ii) No. There exists no such $V$ that contains $1.$

iii) No. There exists no such $V$ that contains $1.$

b) The general condition is that for every $V \in \mathcal{B},$ we have $f^{-1}(V) \in \tau_X$ i.e. the pre-image of the open interval containing $1$ must contain $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning with the function $p$ is good, but the other two don't make sense: *every* interval $V\in\tau_Y$ contains $1$ by definition. In fact, according to the general rule you describe in part b, it seems that you should be able to show that $q$ and $r$ are both continuous!

However, only $q$ is continuous, because your verbal rephrasing in part b is not quite correct. Rather, in order for such a function $f$ to be continuous in this case, the preimage of each open interval containing $1$ must be *an open interval* containing $0.$ While $q$ satisfies this condition, $r$ does not, due to its periodic nature (for sufficiently "small" intervals containing $1,$ the preimage will be the union of countably-infinitely-many disjoint open intervals, exactly one of which will contain $0$).